# Can we use one java script function to multiple input validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We created a JavaScript function to **validate user name**, it is working fine, but if i try to use this 
function to another input validation at the same jsp page, it is showing only text, i included  text color in same function but it is not working in second input validation.
is it possible to get?,
if yes, how can i get?, 
i am starting level in java script, pls give your answer if anything, thank you.

for example , this is my js function:

```
function name_validation()
      {
         if(true){
          var unam=document.getElementById("v2").innerHTML="valid";
          v2.style.color="green"; //this line is not exist in second input validation
                 }
         else{
            var unam=document.getElementById("v2").innerHTML="invalid";
            v2.style.color="red"; //this line is not exist in second input validation
              }
      }
```

this is my jsp code:

```
name:<input type="text" id="name" onchange="name_validation();"><a id="v2"></a>
Father name:<input type="text" id="name" onchange="name_validation();"><a id="v2"></a>
```

Comment: NB: Java is to Javascript as Car is to Carpet.

Comment: hint: pass the controlId to the function and then find the control and perform the validation

Comment: Perform your validation for elements on submit button click or on form submit event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way hope it helps :

```
Name:<input type="text" id="name" onchange="name_validation(this.id);">
Father name:<input type="text" id="father_name" onchange="name_validation(this.id);">

function name_validation(id){ 
  if(document.getElementById(id).value == ''){
    alert(id + 'is null');
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you, i can get alert message with text indicate, but i can't get color of text on second input validation for valid and invalid text. i updated my question again.could you see pls.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass current object like this

```
name:<input type="text" id="name" onchange="name_validation(this);">
Father name:<input type="text" id="father_name" onchange="name_validation(this);">
```

then to do (JQuery):

```
function name_validation(obj) {
var value = $(obj).val();
...
}
```

for javascript

```
function name_validation(obj) {
var value = obj.value;
...
}
```

Comment: thank you alex, i can get alert message with text indicate, but i can't get color of text on second input validation for valid and invalid text. i updated my question again pls see.

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById("v2").style.color="green";` and red as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try following.

```
Name:<input type="text" id="name" class="validate">
Father name:<input type="text" id="father_name" class="validate">
$(function(){
   $('.validate').on('blur',function(){
      if($(this).val() == '')
      {
         $(this).css({'border-color':'red','background':'somecolor '});
      }
      else{
         $(this).css({'background':'somecolor'});
      }   

   });

});
```